# can't understand vue3 style binding

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

In the vue website, I found an example confusing.
In `<script>`, it says

```
const color = ref('green')
function toggleColor() {
  color.value = color.value === 'green' ? 'blue' : 'green'
}
```

In `<template>`,

```
<p :style="{ color }" @click="toggleColor">
    This should be green, and should toggle between green and blue on click.
</p>
```

I don't quite understand how does `:style="{ color }"` work, can anyone help me please?

I have searched online about this problem and didn't seem to find another example of this. I have also tried other ways like deleting the {} but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the complete writing should be `:style="{ color: color }"`.
This should be inspired by the object notation in JavaScript, where the key and value in an object can be omitted if they are the same.

```
<p :style="{ color: color }" @click="toggleColor">
  This should be green, and should toggle between green and blue on click.
</p>
```

Comment: i tried it, you're correct! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The diffrence between the `style` and the `:style` attribute is, that `style` is static and `:style` is dynamic. that means the value of `:style` is not limited to plain text but you can do javascript operations in it, like you do in your example. You pass the content of the variable `color` to the attribute, not the word "color". The function `function toggleColor()` does exactly that, it toggles the value of the variable `color`. and with `@click="toggleColor` you call the function if you click on the element. So everytime you click on the element, the color of the element should change.Hope that helps.

Comment: nicely explained, thx!